# Ember.js 1.0.0: Computed Property in Parent Controller Based on Child ItemController Property Not Updating

Tags: ember.js

I have an *AlertsController* which has multiple *AlertController* children underneath it.  When a user clicks on an alert I set an **isSelected** flag to true in the *AlertController* from the *AlertView*.  I then have a computed property in *AlertsController* that should return the number of selected alerts.

The AlertsController and AlertController look like this:

```
App.AlertsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'Alert',
    //numSelected doesn't update when isSelected flag in an alert changes
    numSelected: function(){
        return this.filterProperty('isSelected', true).get('length');
    }.property('@each.isSelected')       
});

App.AlertController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isSelected : false,
});
```

I know the **isSelected** property in the *AlertController* is updating but the value for **numSelected** in the *AlertsController* is only computed once when the page loads.

I recreated my issue in the following fiddle:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLAnF/8/

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong here?  Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define `isSelected` in `App.AlertController`:

```
App.AlertController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // isSelected : false,
});
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BQmww/1/

The reason is that, if you define `isSelected` explicitly in `App.AlertController`, it will not be available in the proxied `content` object (and therefore it will not be accessible by `App.AlertsController`).

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  I'm a little confused by the provided 'content' object.  Does this mean anytime you want to access a property from another controller you can't explicitly define that property in the "owning" controller?  It seems like it makes the code a little harder to read since you won't know that property exists when looking at the AlertController code.